# How to detect certain conditions in an encrypted string and decrypt it?- Python

Tags: python, string, function

I'm trying to make three different functions to decrypt an encrypted string. The follow conditions are :

**(1)** if the character "T" (uppercase) is found, it implies that the next three characters must be 
      lowercase vowels.

**(2)** If rule 1 is met, the position will be a continuous 6-digit number from the fourth position with 
      respect to the "T" character. The odd ones correspond to the first coordinate field and the pairs 
      to the second coordinate field.

For example:

```py
Taeo135789->[158,379]
Tauo123456->[135,246]
```

**(3)** After the digits, an acronym of 3 is presented. I want to print this separately.

**Example:**

```
INPUT: dsa2wtasfwTaeo135789konsadfa241

OUTPUT: (Taeo135789kon)
 Taeo
 [158,379]
 kon
```

I already tried:

```py
def first_rule(str_encript):
  vowels = "aeiou"
  str_encript = str(str_encript)
  for s in str_encript:
    if "T" in s:

      (next three characters must be lowercase vowels.)

    else:
      print("Error in the encrypted str\n")
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: should be able to accomplish with a regex. Something like: `r"(T)([aeiou]{3})(\d{6})(\w{3})"`

Comment: Why have you posted code if you aren't going to ask about it?  If you want help fixing it, you have to explain what the problem with it is.

Comment: @BrianJoseph I know, but what I want to do is create this three different functions. I'll update my code, for some reason I couldn't paste it all

Comment: @ScottHunter you are right, but I think I'm explaining right what is the problem: decrypt an encrypted string with certain conditions using functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a reqular expression to extract all the examples of this pattern from a string:

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r'(T[aeiou]{3})(\d{6})([a-z]{3})')

def first_rule(encrypted):
    for match in pat.finditer(encrypted):
        t_str, nums, acro = match.group(1, 2, 3)
        coordinates = [int(''.join(nums[x::2])) for x in range(2)]
        print(t_str, coordinates , acro, sep='\n')

first_rule('dsa2wtasfwTaeo135789konsadfa241')
# Taeo
# [158, 379]
# kon
```

If you really can't use the `re` module (which is a built-in library distributed with Python), then you can achieve a similar result scanning the string with `enumerate`:

```
def first_rule(encrypted):
    for i, c in enumerate(encrypted):
        if c == 'T':
            t_str = encrypted[i+1:i+4]
            if len(t_str) != 3 or any(x not in 'aeiou' for x in t_str):
                continue
            t_str = 'T' + t_str
            nums = encrypted[i+4:i+10]
            if len(nums) != 6 or any(x not in '0123456789' for x in nums):
                continue
            coordinates = [int(''.join(nums[x::2])) for x in range(2)]
            acro = encrypted[i+10:i+13]
            if len(acro) != 3 or any(x not in 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm' for x in acro):
                continue
            print(t_str, coordinates , acro, sep='\n')
```

By tracking the index we're on in the string, we can look ahead of the `T` to do our matching.

Comment: This is what exactly I'm trying to do, but without using libraries, just using def functions, and for each one of the rules make a different function